# How to format a bash loop using sed, awk, grep, and wc

Tags: shell-script, ksh

So I have a text file that I need to get extract specific lines out of and count the number of times a number in a specific column appears.  I have about 100 or so of these files.  I can get it done in small steps but want to get it done using bash/ksh:

```
foreach i *h3
sed '4p;55p;77q;d' $i >> output.txt
end
```

^^^^this will just extract the lines I need from each h3 file

```
awk '{print $6}' output.txt | grep 'P2' | wc -l
```

^^^this will just extract column 6 from output.txt and count the number of times P2 appears in column 6

Is there a way I can combine all of this into a bash/ksh script?

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly:

- you want to count how many times there is "P2" anywhere within the 6th field of lines 4,55 and 77 of a few files (named *h3)?

You could do this with 1 awk:

```
awk '
( FNR==4 || FNR==55 || FNR==77 ) {
    if ( $6 ~ "P2" ) { occurence++ } 
}
END {
    printf "There was: %d P2 ", occurence
    printf " among the 6th field on lines 4,55 or 77 of the *h3 files\n"
}' *h3
```

Note: change `$6 ~ "P2"` into `$6 == "P2"` if you want an exact match (instead of a grep, as you did use in your own example, so that it also matches: `somethingP2otherthing` and variants thereof)

FNR = File's Number of Records = number of lines into the current file (ie, starts again at 1 at each file's first line)
 (Current file whose name can also be known by the internal variable: FILENAME)

(NR = here would not work, as it is the (total) Number or Records read since the beginning (not since the beginning of the current file) )

Comment: +1. can be shortened using a regexp match for FNR: `FNR ~ /^(4|55|77)$/ && $6 ~ /P2/ {occurence++}; END{ .... }`

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Here's one way

```
p2_count=0
for f in *h3; do
    for ((n=1; n<=77; n++)); do
        IFS= read -r line
        if [[ $n == 4|55|77 ]]; then
            echo "$line"
            set -f
            set -- $line
            set +f
            if [[ $6 == *P2* ]]; then
                ((p2_count++))
            fi
        fi
    done < "$f"
done > output.txt
echo "saw P2 in 6th column $p2_count times"
```

Comment: Kudos for a pure shell version

Answer (score 0):

Or using a **bash** one-liner:

```
for i in *h3; do sed '4p;55p;77q;d' $i | awk '{print $6}' | grep 'P2'; done | wc -l
```

Or shorter using `grep -c`:

```
for i in *h3; do sed '4p;55p;77q;d' $i | awk '{print $6}'; done | grep -c 'P2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when a question asks "how do I process a bunch of text files using ***specific tool(s)*** in a bash loop?", the answer is, in part, "Don't use a bash loop, use (some or all of) the tool(s) themselves".  Sometimes part of the answer is even "Don't use those tools, use this instead".

What you want can be done with `awk` alone, no need for a shell loop.  Or `sed` or `grep` or `wc`:

```awk
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"}
     FNR ~ /^(4|10|17)$/ && $6 ~ /P2/ {count++}
     ENDFILE { print FILENAME, count; count=0 }' *h3
```

Note: [ENDFILE](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html)  is specific to GNU `awk`.  It won't work with other versions of `awk`.

And this version also prints a cumulative total for all files:

```awk
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"}
     FNR ~ /^(4|10|17)$/ && $6 ~ /P2/ {count++; total++}
     ENDFILE { print FILENAME, count; count=0 }
     END { print "---", total,"total" }' *h3
```

The `END{}` block prints the total and also makes a crude attempt to distinguish the actual total from any files that happen to have the filename "total".  It does this by printing `---` in the first field, then the total, and then the string `total` in the third field.  This is far from perfect but is good enough in many cases.  It's better than, like `wc`, not making the attempt at all.